# Closing 128 new Preview documents without saving

Tags: macos, preview

I opened **128** `.png` files in Preview, hoping to use it to create a PDF out of them, as I believe was possible in earlier versions using the *New from clipboard* trick, but apparently, on Yosemite, not any more.

Now I want to close the newly created documents, but it'll require me to click *Don't Save* 128 times.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Well, quitting the application via Activity Monitor or Terminal (`killall Preview`) should do it, but it might be that all the windows reopen when it's next started. Maybe there's a hidden option to influence that behaviour but I'm not sure. Also you don't need to click it, with luck, the "Don't Save" option is highlighted and pressing Space will suffice (I think you need to enable that in System Preferences), so holding Cmd-W and Space for some time might close them all.

Comment: force quit preview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd Force-Quit it using the Apple Menu dialog, and then clear the saved state files from the storage so that Preview doesn't try to reopen those documents next time it starts.

From Finder:

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>     <kbd>G</kbd>
- Copy/paste `~/Library/Saved Application State`

Delete the folder com.apple.Preview.savedState and you're set for the next start of Preview to be clean.

Comment: thank you!! this was driving me crazy

Answer (score 6):

As of Yosemite, at least, there's a much easier way. Just choose Quit from the File menu.

Preview will ask you if you want to review changes. If you say no, you're done!

Comment: That's very much dependent on having 'ask to keep changes when closing documents' set in system prefs > general

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what Chris and Tetsujin collectively said:

1. Open System Preferences (Apple Menu, System Preferences...)
2. Click "General"
3. Make sure "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" and "Close windows when quitting an app" are both checked
4. Go back to Preview, click the "Preview" menu, and click "Quit Preview"

Comment: This is the answer for the newest macOS (2023)